# Low Alphabet and entries range (filtering)

Tags: low-alphabet

I have two tabs - first should to display doctors names starting from A-N and second one names starting from O-Z

```
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="providers1">
    {exp:low_alphabet:entries channel="doctors" alpha_field="doctor_short_name" alpha_groups="A-N" alpha_filter="A-N"}
        {photos limit="1"}
                <img src="{photos:image_thumbnail}" alt="{photos:image_title}" class="img-responsive">
        {/photos}<br>
        <a href="{site_url}index.php/meet_us/{url_title}">{title}</a>
    {/exp:low_alphabet:entries}  
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="providers2">
    {exp:low_alphabet:entries channel="doctors" alpha_field="doctor_short_name" alpha_groups="O-Z" alpha_filter="O-Z"}
        <a href="{site_url}index.php/meet_us/{url_title}">{title}</a>
    {/exp:low_alphabet:entries}    
  </div>
```

but somehow both tabs are displaying same entries not triggering Low Alphabet filter.

Any clue what can be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Question asked and answered here: https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/low-alphabet-and-ee-2-7-3

Comment: Respond in a related link